# Convert file uri to content uri

Tags: android

i want to choose a file (via file chooser) from astro manager (in my case  a *.pdf or *.doc) but the uri contains only the file path (`"sdcard/my_folder/test.pdf"`). For my application i need the content path like that from image chooser (content://media/external/images/media/2
). Is there any way to convert a `"file:///"`  to `"content://"` uri?

Or has anybody an other idea how to solve that problem?

best regards

UPDATE: the main problem is that after i choose my file with filechooser valuecallback.onReceiveValue(uri) method adds a "/" behind the path. So i get an uri like this: "sdcard/my_folder/test.pdf/" and my application thinks pdf is a folder. When i use content uri from image chooser it works.

Comment: sdcard/my_folder/test.pdf this is right url for read data from sdcard in mobile device

Answer (score 19):

Like @CommmonsWare said, there is no easy way to convert any type of files into content:// .
But here is how I convert an image File into content://

```
public static Uri getImageContentUri(Context context, File imageFile) {
    String filePath = imageFile.getAbsolutePath();
    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            new String[] { MediaStore.Images.Media._ID },
            MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA + "=? ",
            new String[] { filePath }, null);

    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        int id = cursor.getInt(cursor
                .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns._ID));
        Uri baseUri = Uri.parse("content://media/external/images/media");
        return Uri.withAppendedPath(baseUri, "" + id);
    } else {
        if (imageFile.exists()) {
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, filePath);
            return context.getContentResolver().insert(
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this for - file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.pkg_name/files/out.mp4, but its returning *null*. I also tried changing `MediaStore.Images.Media` to `MediaStore.Video.Media`, but still no luck

Comment: Thanks, this is the only solution which worked for me on my Android-N device. My app is targeting API 24.

Comment: @Ben Lee when I try to decode this image in bitmap it returns null.

Comment: This work! Where can I learn more about Android Cursor and .query()? How did you learn this? I couldn't find it in the Android doc.

Answer (score 10):

Here is a simpler way to consider, which may be suitable for you.

I use it for sharing downloaded images on google plus from my android app:

```
/**
 * Converts a file to a content uri, by inserting it into the media store.
 * Requires this permission: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
 */
protected static Uri convertFileToContentUri(Context context, File file) throws Exception {

    //Uri localImageUri = Uri.fromFile(localImageFile); // Not suitable as it's not a content Uri

    ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
    String imagePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
    String imageName = null;
    String imageDescription = null;
    String uriString = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(cr, imagePath, imageName, imageDescription);
    return Uri.parse(uriString);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

One simple way to achieve this could be by using **MediaScannerConnection**

```
File file = new File("pathname");
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(getContext(), new String[]{file.getAbsolutePath()}, null /*mimeTypes*/, new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScanCompleted(String s, Uri uri) {
                // uri is in format content://...
            }
        });
```

Comment: This is very clever, I am declaring the file to the gallery anyway. Generates something like: `content://media/external_primary/images/media/1000002103` which is unfortunately not recognized by my webview but I still wanted to add the upvote.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me and what I use in my Share Folder app:

1. Create a folder called xml under resources
2. Add a file_paths.xml to it, with following line in it:

```
<files-path name="internal" path="/"/>
```

3. Add a File provider authority in the manifest, as:

```
<provider android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
               android:authorities="com.dasmic.filebrowser.FileProvider"
               android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"
               android:exported="false"
               android:grantUriPermissions="true">
               <meta-data
                    android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                    android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
</provider>
```

4.Transfer file to a different intent with 'content://' as follows:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION); //Required for Android 8+
Uri data = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "com.dasmic.filebrowser.FileProvider", file);
intent.setDataAndType(data, type);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: what is com.dasmic.filebrowser.FileProvider? where is the code?

Answer (score 2):

you can achieve it my using FileProvider

**step 1:**
create a `java` file and `extends` it with `FileProvider`

```
public class MyFileProvider extends FileProvider {

}
```

**step 2:**
create an `xml` resource file in `res/xml/` directory and copy this code in it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</paths>
```

**step 3:**
in your `manifest` file, under `<Application>` tag add this code

```
<provider
            android:name="MyFileProvider" <!-- java file created above -->
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.MyFileProvider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/> <!-- xml file created above -->
        </provider>
```

**Step 4:** 
use this code to get `Uri` in `content://` format

```
Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(CameraActivity.this, "your.package.name.MyFileProvider", file /* file whose Uri is required */);
```

**Note:**
you may need to add read permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Uri myUri = Uri.fromFile(new File("/sdcard/cats.jpg"));
```

Or with:

```
Uri myUri = Uri.parse(new File("/sdcard/cats.jpg").toString());
```