# How to extract the real file URI or file data from a path that looks like "/content:/media/external/video/media/19"?

Tags: android

I am desperately trying to send a captured video to a server. The problem is that the URI that is given by the built-in camera application is not the real file path. It looks like this - `/content:/media/external/video/media/19`.

How can I access the real path or the data directly from this kind of URIs?

After reading the android documentation I saw that it looks like a content provider's notation, but I still don't have a clue how to reach the data that I need. Please help!!!

thanks in advance

Comment: This question is answered there please check https://stackoverflow.com/a/52641312/6086086

Comment: This question is answered here please check https://stackoverflow.com/a/52641312/6086086

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can I access the real path or the data directly from this kind of URIs?

You don't. It might not exist as a file. Or, it might not exist as a file that you can read except via the `ContentProvider`.

Instead, use a `ContentResolver` to open an `InputStream` on that `Uri`, and use that `InputStream` to transfer the data to a server.

Comment: Just to show you an example - this is my code:

`InputStream is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(Uri.parse(YOUR_URI_STRING)));`

Comment: How to get type of such URIs? I mean how to know its pdf or ppt or even wav or mp3 file?

Comment: @JRC: If you look in the upper-right corner of your Web page, you will see an "Ask Question" button. Please use that, rather than hijacking other questions. That being said, ask the `MediaStore` for the `MIME_TYPE` of your content.

Answer (score 4):

```
public String getRealPathFromURI(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
  Cursor cursor = null;
  try { 
    String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri,  proj, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
  } finally {
    if (cursor != null) {
      cursor.close();
    }
  }
}
```

see following post for 
[Get filename and path from URI from mediastore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401579/get-filename-and-path-from-uri-from-mediastore)