# FileNotFoundException while uploading image using Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit2, image-uploading, multipart

I tried to upload an image using Retrofit but I am getting this error:

`Unable to submit post to API: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /document/image:30231: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)`

My interface is like this:

```
public interface MyService{
    @Multipart
    @POST("/url")
    Call<ResponseBody> addNewEvent( @Part("case_Id") int caseId,@Part MultipartBody.Part(file);
}
```

On Button click, `selectImage()` function is called:

```
private void selectImage() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Please select image",1);
}
```

In the `onActivityResult` part, I did the following:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode!=RESULT_CANCELED && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
        FilePathUri = data.getData();
        doAddNewEvent();
    }
}
```

From above, `doAddNewEvent()` function is called:

```
public void doAddNewEvent() {
    File file = new File(FilePathuri.getPath());
    RequestBody requestFile=RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), file);
    MultipartBody.Part body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("image", file.getName(), requestFile);

 apiService.addNewEvent(inputCaseId, body).enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {                    
                ResponseBody addEventResponse = response.body();
                Log.d("as", "response: " + addEventResponse);
                finish();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e("as", "Unable to submit post to API");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: There is some problem in your `getPath()` debug your code. Check [This discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7305504/convert-file-uri-to-content-uri) or you can also search for similar .

Comment: On `FilePathUri.getPath()`, I get this:  `/document/image:23165`

Comment: `java.io.FileNotFoundException: /document/image:30231:`. Indeed that is no valid path on the file system. Thats a part of a content scheme. The complete scheme is given by FilePathUri.toString().

Comment: Is there any way that I can get the right path?

Comment: You should ask: is there any way that i can retrofit let use the obtained uri directly? Or the content scheme? Can you let retrofit upload files from a stream? From an InputStream?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a problem to get file path

**Try with this :**

```
if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode!=RESULT_CANCELED && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {

            FilePathStr = null;

            if (data != null) {



                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                String[] filePath = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
                Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePath,
                        null, null, null);
                c.moveToFirst();
                int columnIndex = c.getColumnIndex(filePath[0]);
                FilePathStr = c.getString(columnIndex);
                c.close();
                doAddNewEvent();




            }

        }
```

and make multipart using string path

```
MultipartBody.Part body = null;

            if (FilePathStr != null) {
                File file = new File(FilePathStr );
                RequestBody reqFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), file);
                body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("image", file.getName(), reqFile);

            }
```

Comment: `FilePathUri = c.getString(columnIndex)` Here, FilePathUri is of Uri type so it will give an error.

Comment: check with updated ans , and please take string instead of URI

Comment: But `data.getData()` required Uri type not String

Comment: okay @sangeeta , now please check i remove URI Code

it will works

Comment: Welcome and now you can do right tick with this answer