# Android: How to convert File Uri to Content Uri

Tags: android, uri

We need to convert a file path to a content uri and pass on for subsequent processing to a common component. When we use "Uri.fromFile(file)" it returns a file uri and not a content uri. Please let us know how to get this converted. Appreciate your help.

```
for (File file : fileBaseFolder.listFiles()) {
    Uri convertedUri = Uri.fromFile(file);//Need to convert this Uri to a Content uri
    .........
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use FileProvider to serve your file.

It gives nice uries.

```
FileProvider.getUriForFile().
```

You can serve all files except those from removable micro sd card.

Answer (score 1):

try [MediaScannerConnection.scanFile](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaScannerConnection#scanFile(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20android.media.MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener))

```java
for (File file : fileBaseFolder.listFiles()) {
    MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this, new String[] { file.getAbsolutePath() }, null,
            (path, uri) -> Log.i(TAG, uri.toString()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the below link for the solution.

https://www.thetopsites.net/article/52460984.shtml

Also, the same question is asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7305504/convert-file-uri-to-content-uri).

Comment: Thanks Mahendra. The limitation with this method seems to be that it might not work for generic files, am I right ?

Comment: What do you consider to be generic files? And which of the many solutions proposed in that link are you talking about?